# What is the "Block Element" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Using Firefox 38.6.0 on RHEL7, if I right click on an image on a webpage, I can see: "Block element".

If I accidentally blocked an image, how can I enable it again, where is the list of blocked elements in Firefox? I only have ublock as an Add-on, I don't think this feature is for this add-on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is definitely uBlock. I also use uBlock and if I right click on an image, the uBlock logo is shown next to "Block Element".

[image: Block Element]

To remove the filter, click on uBlock and click the gear to open the Dashboard.

[image: Dashboard]

Then go to My filters and remove the ones you accidentally added. Apply changes and it should be fine.

[image: My filters]